# android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. (RxJava)

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I found many articles regarding the error I am getting, I know we can only update UI from the main thread only. Let me tell you the whole error I am getting:

```
E/RxEroor: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already cancelled/disposed of the flow or the exception has nowhere to go, to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I am getting the error by using this:

```
  RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(throwable -> {
        Log.e("RxEroor",throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
    });
```

I am using rxjava to observe things from a retrofit network call. Here is my call to ViewModel from fragment to fetch data.

```
compositeDisposable.add(songsOfCategoryViewModel.getAllSongs(1)
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<ServerResponse<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull ServerResponse<JsonObject> jsonObjectServerResponse) {

                    if (jsonObjectServerResponse.isStatus()){
                        Log.i("Songs Of Category",jsonObjectServerResponse.getData().toString());
                        List<SongModel> serverSongList = new Gson()
                                .fromJson(jsonObjectServerResponse.getData().get("songs")
                                        .getAsJsonArray(),new TypeToken<List<SongModel>>(){}.getType());

                        localSongList.addAll(serverSongList);
                        songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      /*  Observable
                                .fromIterable(serverSongList)
                                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<SongModel>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull SongModel songModel) {
                                        Log.i("Song",songModel.getTitle());
                                        localSongList.add(songModel);
                                        songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {
                                        Log.i("onComplete","Called");

                                    }
                                });
                        */

                    }else {
                        Log.e("Error",jsonObjectServerResponse.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());

                }
            }));
```

As you can see I have provided AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() to subscribeOn. I m getting the data on onSucces method but recyclerview adapter not updating it on UI.

And let me tell you most tricky part: if I switch the app to the foreground by locking the screen or pressing the home button and return to the app, my UI get updated with the data which I have received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` not `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` . Use as

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

> [subscribeOn](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html) used to specify the Scheduler on which an Observable will operate. In your case it will be an IO scheduler.
>
> [ObserveOn](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html) is used specify the Scheduler on which an observer will observe this Observable i.e the completion in this case it will be Main thread

Comment: omg...how can i do silly mistake..i know the fundamentals..but as I am new I have done it..thank you..